# Is computing the logarithm of a matrix required to compute non-integral powers of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

If you try to perform a simple Taylor expansion of the function $e^{p \ln{M}}$ with $M$ a $N \times N$ matrix, you get an infinite series of terms with powers of $\ln{M}$

Does there exist computationally cheaper methods to compute $M^p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ M\ $ is [*diagonalisable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), with $\ M=PDP^{-1}\ $ and $\ D\ $ diagonal, you can take $\ M^p\ $ to be $\ PD^pP^{-1}\ $, where
$$
D^p=\begin{pmatrix}
d_1^p&0&\dots&0\\
0&d_2^p&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\dots&d_N^p\ .
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In general, I don't believe it's possible to give any reasonable definition of $\ M^p\ $ for *all* real $\ p\ $ and an *arbitrary* matrix $\ M\ $. If
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}\ ,
$$
for instance, then there doesn't exist any matrix $\ A\ $ such that $\ A^2=M\ $, so how would you then define $\ M^\frac{1}{2}\ $?

Comment: it would be an interesting follow-up question if one can find an algebraically complete extension of the matrix algebra where these always have solutions (or the solutions are used formally, just like $i = \sqrt{-1}$ was for some time)